# How can I avoid a Bad Request, for a URL, when it does not appear in the Source Code?

Tags: resources, http-status-code-404, bad-request, broken-links, http-status-code-410

I have just used Google Developer Tools, to perform a site Audit.  The Audit is suggesting to fix/remove Broken links to the following resources:

```
https://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.7.0
https://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0
https://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.7.0
https://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/fonts/star.ttf
https://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/fonts/star.woff
```

I also used an additional 3rd party tool, which also suggested to fix/remove the above URLs.  Their suggestion was:

> The following requests are returning 404/410 responses. Either fix the
>   broken links, or remove the references to the non-existent resources.

The problem is, the above URLs do not appear within the Source Code nor can I find such files within the Web Files.

Any ideas why the above links are not appearing in the Source Code and how this can be resolved?  My only assumption, is that the above URLs are dynamically created in the Backend and the Audit tools are referring to the server side coding rather than the outputted HTML etc.